# Module has no exported member 'http' [2305]

Tags: angular6

Hello I am trying to import http call from '@angular/common/http' and am getting error message that module has no exported member 'http'

Error:[ts] Module '"e:/car/node_modules/@angular/common/http"' has no exported member 'Http'. [2305]

```js
import {
  RouterModule
} from '@angular/router';
import {
  BrowserModule
} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  NgModule
} from '@angular/core';

import {
  AppRoutingModule
} from './app-routing.module';
import {
  AppComponent
} from './app.component';
import {
  HomeComponent
} from './home/home.component';
import {
  HttpClientModule
} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([{
      path: '',
      component: HomeComponent
    }])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```js
import {
  Http
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  products = [];
  fetchData = function() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:5555/products').subscribe(
      (res: Response) => {
        this.products = res.json();
      }
    );
  };
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

}
```

the below code is used for inserting json file which includes the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpClientModule` will inject `HttpClient` service not the `Http`.

Please use `HttpClient` in constructor injection in the `HomeComponent`.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
```

For Reference created sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zxa3dk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) code.

Comment: Hello Ranjit the code works fine now but I am unable to fetch data from json server could you please help me out with that issue

Below is the export class

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  products = [];
  fetchData = function() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:5555/products').subscribe (
      (res: Response) => {
        this.products = res.json();
      }
    );
  };
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

}

Comment: For reference created sample code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zxa3dk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I have added a products.json file with a set of values and given the localhost address:5555 but even after using this.http.get('localhost:5555/products').subscribe ( (res: Response) => { this.products = res.json(); } );  it is not fetching the data and also not showing the error message in the browser 

P.S:I have installed the json server and server is working fine after manipulating the values in server 

used "npm install -g json-server" for installing

extremely sorry if there is any silly mistake from my end

Comment: Instead of `this.products = res.json();` use `this.products = res;`. And check in chrome dev tool is the `http://localhost:5555/products` returning any data.

Comment: thanks a lot  for the help it got worked now in case any issues I will ask another question or comment here and alo if you hav any tutorials or links for learning CRUD Operations and Grids in angular please send me

Comment: For Detailed angular tutorial please go through https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/ . This has a detailed and step by step chapters and with sample example.